# VB6 to .Net COM Port Communication

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, serial-port, vb6-migration

I am having problem in sending data through serial port. In VB6 I am using the code like this

```
Public Sub SendProtokoll(sProtoString As String)
 Debug.Print Chr(1) & " " & sProtoString & Chr(4)
 If mainform.MSComm1.PortOpen = True Then 
   mainform.MSComm1.Output = Chr(1) & " " & sProtoString & Chr(4)
 End if
End Sub
```

Here sProtoString is a Hexadecimal value, its sending the data to through Serial port correctly without any issues... I am able to send data and receive response.

In VB.Net application I am sending the data like this

```
Public Sub SendProtokoll(sProtoString As String)
    Dim strSendText As String
    strSentText = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(1) + " " + sProtoString + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(4)
    Try
        COMPort.Write(strSentText, 0, strSendText.Length)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message & "  Check CTS signal or set Flow Control to None.")
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I send the data in .Net I am not getting any response from the HMI device, I would like to know whats the mistake I am doing here.

Can anyone help me.

In VB6 I am using MSComm control, in .Net I am using Imports System.IO.Ports

For Receiver I am using the following code

```
 Private Sub Receiver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles COMPort.DataReceived
    Dim RXByte As Byte
    Do
        RXCnt = 0
        Do
            RXByte = COMPort.ReadByte
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte >> 4) ' Convert each byte to two hexadecimal characters
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            RXArray(RXCnt) = LookUpTable(RXByte And 15)
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            RXArray(RXCnt) = " "
            RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            SpaceCount = (SpaceCount + 1) And 31      ' Insert spaces and CRLF for better readability
            If SpaceCount = 0 Then                    ' Insert CRLF after 32 numbers
                RXArray(RXCnt) = Chr(13) ' CR
                RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
                RXArray(RXCnt) = Chr(10) ' LF
                RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
            Else
                If (SpaceCount And 3) = 0 Then        ' Insert two extra spaces for each 4 numbers
                    RXArray(RXCnt) = " "
                    RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
                    RXArray(RXCnt) = " "
                    RXCnt = RXCnt + 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop Until (COMPort.BytesToRead = 0)
        '----- End of communication protocol handling -------------------------------------------------------------
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Display)) ' Start "Display" on the UI thread
    Loop Until (COMPort.BytesToRead = 0)  ' Don't return if more bytes have become available in the meantime
End Sub
```

Comment: try to set the communication properties of the serial port:Example https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SerialPort-brief-Example-ac0d5004

Comment: Hassan thanks for your response, I tried it but it did not worked

Comment: what is  the raised  exception?

Comment: No exception came :(

Comment: You are complaining about not getting a response but you did not post any code that actually tries to read the response.  When you are this confused about the code then it is probably best to keep using MSComm, it works fine in a VB.NET app as well.

Comment: Hans Passant: I had included the Receiver code now

Comment: For VB6 Application Receiver works perfectly

Comment: `Here sProtoString is a Hexadecimal value...` - Do you mean a string representation of binary data that is then encoded to a byte stream using the SerialPort's encoder.  Perhaps the receiving device expects a raw byte stream representation of the data.  A Hex representation of the number 1 as a `Short` is "0100".  If this was sent as a raw `Short`, it would be 2 bytes {01 00}; as a Hex string it will be 4 bytes {48 49 48 48} in an ASCI encoding.  My point is that you should verify what your device expects to receive.

Comment: TnTinMn: I had solved the problem as you had mentioned :) thanks